# Create a closure in Erlang: why are variables not bound?

Tags: erlang, closures, shadowing

I have a piece of code that goes like this:

```
Fi_F = fun (F, I, Xs) -> 
           fun ( X ) -> 
                F( x_to_list(X, Xs, I) ) 
           end 
end,
```

I just need to turn a function of list to a function of one number. For example with Xs = [1,2,3] and I = 2, I expect this to grant me with function:

```
fun ( X ) -> F([ 1, X, 3]) end.
```

But somehow F, I and X are shadowed, not closured, so it fails in x_to_list with an empty list.

I'm still new to Erlang and think I'm missing something more conceptual, than a mere syntax problem.

**UPD:** Found a bug. I wrote x_to_list/3 this way:

```
x_to_list( X, L, I ) ->
    lists:sublist(L, I) ++ [ X ] ++ lists:nthtail(I+1, L).
```

So it counts list elements from 0, not 1. When I call it with I = 3, it fails. So this is not about closuring.

I still have shadowing warnings though, but it is completely another issue.

Comment: Could you show the definition of `x_to_list`? The error must be there, because variables and lambdas defined this way always form a closure.

Comment: Oh! I've found a mistake in mine. It's not a shadowing issue, just a pure inaccuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat quick and dirty implementation of `x_to_list/3` (just to test) would be:

```
x_to_list(X, Xs, I) ->
   { Pre, Post } = lists:split(I-1, Xs),
   Pre ++ [X] ++ tl(Post).
```

Then, your code works without problems:

```
> Q = fun ( F, I, Xs ) -> fun (X) -> F( x_to_list(X, Xs, I)) end end.
> Y = Q( fun(L) -> io:format("~p, ~p, ~p~n", L) end, 2, [1,2,3] ).
> Y(4).
1, 4, 3
ok
```